# Why no switch on pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, switch-statement

For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void why_cant_we_switch_him(void *ptr)
{
    switch (ptr) {
        case NULL:
            printf("NULL!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("%p!\n", ptr);
            break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    void *foo = "toast";
    why_cant_we_switch_him(foo);
    return 0;
}

gcc test.c -o test
test.c: In function 'why_cant_we_switch_him':
test.c:5: error: switch quantity not an integer
test.c:6: error: pointers are not permitted as case values
```

Just curious. Is this a technical limitation?

#### EDIT

People seem to think there is only one constant pointer expression. Is that is really true, though? For instance, here is a common paradigm in Objective-C (it is really only C aside from `NSString`, `id` and `nil`, which are merely a pointers, so it is still relevant — I just wanted to point out that there *is*, in fact, a common use for it, despite this being only a technical question):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static NSString * const kMyConstantObject = @"Foo";

void why_cant_we_switch_him(id ptr)
{
    switch (ptr) {
        case kMyConstantObject: // (Note that we are comparing pointers, not string values.)
            printf("We found him!\n");
            break;
        case nil:
            printf("He appears to be nil (or NULL, whichever you prefer).\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("%p!\n", ptr);
            break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    NSString *foo = @"toast";
    why_cant_we_switch_him(foo);
    foo = kMyConstantObject;
    why_cant_we_switch_him(foo);

    return 0;
}

gcc test.c -o test -framework Foundation
test.c: In function 'why_cant_we_switch_him':
test.c:5: error: switch quantity not an integer
test.c:6: error: pointers are not permitted as case values
```

It appears that the reason is that switch only allows integral values (as the compiler warning said). So I suppose a better question would be to ask why this is the case? (though it is probably too late now.)

Comment: Why would you want to?  Isn't `if (ptr) { ... } else { ... }` good enough for you?

Comment: Why do you want to switch on a pointer? `if(ptr)` not good enough for you or something?

Comment: Why ask why? Its a reasonable language question, with a well written example. Whether or not its a good idea is not on trial here.

Comment: It was just a question about how the language works. Of course `if (ptr != NULL)` is "good enough" (certainly preferable in this simple case), but there are cases where I have a list of pointers to check, and I found it a bit strange that this syntax didn't work with it — I was just asking why.

Comment: switch is a generalization of a jump table.  Jump tables are indexed with integers, not pointers.  If your case labels are too spread out the compiler probably converts most or all of them to if/else.  There's no benefit from using switch/case with non-integral labels instead of if/else.

Comment: @ Dan Olson: Ease of maintenance and readability might be considered an advantage, even of there is no code generation advantage.

Comment: i dont mean to rain on anyones parade, but isn't this the reason preprocessor macros exist, so we if we don't like the "syntax" we can come up with our own... i mean if you just like how 'pretty' switch is, just make a macro that secretly uses "if-then-else" which seems like the elephant in the corner that nobody wants to talk about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Switch statements operate on integral values only. That's why the error message is "switch quantity not an integer." I don't think it's a technical limitation so much as it's outside the language syntax.

Comment: It is more semantic than syntactic - syntactically, you can't tell the difference between '`int ptr; ... switch (ptr)`' and '`void *ptr; ... switch (ptr)`', but semantically, there is a difference.  But you are right; the language does not allow 'switch on non-integral type'.

Comment: It is possible to reinterpret a pointer into a DWORD or QWORD and just use that, though, which makes `void *ptr` look like `int ptr`. Anything is possible, really, it just depends on how many `*` and `&` you're willing to have in one line. That doesn't mean everything is good to do, but a pointer-based switch seems safe-ish.

Answer (score 15):

A switch compares the variable with a set of *compile-time* constants. Other than null, I can't see any valid compile time constants that you might compare a pointer with. For example:

```
switch (ptr) { 
   case &var1: printf ("Pointing to var1"); break;
   case &var2: printf ("Pointing to var2"); break;
}
```

var1 and var2 are likely different in each run of the program, and would not be compile time constants. One possibility might be that they are addresses of memory-mapped ports that are always fixed, but otherwise I don't see how you could easily expand this from your two cases (null / not-null).

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO. If the `case` needs to be compile-time constants, it makes sense that you can't use pointers with a switch.

Comment: What about pointer to members like `Foo::bar`. Of course, they are not absolute pointers, so your argument still holds, but they don't work in switch expressions, which is a pitty in my opinion.

Answer (score 14):

#### Because there is only one constant pointer expression

Given that only a single constant pointer expression exists, the `switch` statement has little to offer pointer expressions. You have cited essentially the only possible construction.

Comment: Bam. This seems to be the reason. I'm not sure why it escaped nearly everyone else that switch cases operated off of constants.

Comment: You could have a other constant pointer expressions like "char * vgabuffer = (char *)(0xB800)"

Comment: The addresses of variables that have static storage duration are also constant.

Comment: @caf: no, C99 calls those *address constants* .. see 6.6 (9). You cannot, for example, get away with `int y; int x[&y];`

Comment: @Tarydon: perhaps I should have said *"there is only one portable constant ..."* :-)

Comment: Well, of course not - using a pointer value as an array size is nonsensical (`int x[NULL];` is also wrong!).  However, it seems to me that if, hypothetically, `switch` *were* extended to deal with pointers, then logically *address constants* would be needed as the `case` expressions.

Comment: Pointers in switches are useful when dealing with memory-mapped peripherals in microcontrollers.

Comment: I still do not understand. If I have some named `MyClass*` variables and then obtain array of `MyClass*`, why not use switch to map named variables to array elements?

Comment: Downvoted because the bolded claim is unclear, not explained, and seems false. What do you mean "there is only one constant pointer expression"? If there's only one, why don't you tell us what it is? ...As @oyvind points out, memory-mapped peripherals are at constant addresses - thus my "seems false", based on my best guess at the meaning.

Answer (score 8):

`switch` statements operate on integral expressions only.   A pointer is not an integral expression.

You can explicitly convert a pointer to an integral type if you wanted to, but the proposed code is a little strange and unnatural.

**So to answer your question exactly: Because there is no implicit conversion between a pointer and an integral type.**

Answer (score 6):

Cast ptr to an int and try again:

```
switch( (int)ptr )
```

or to be more correct:

```
switch( (intptr_t)ptr ) // C99 integer type to hold a pointer
```

Comment: The appropriate workaround for compiler not supporting the one legitimate use of switch on pointer. I like that.

Comment: This only works assuming `sizeof(int) == sizeof(ptr)` on the target platform. That's not always the case.

Comment: You have no guarantee that an `int` is large enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: So you'd use intptr then, but since the only comparison you can really make is against 0, there's no point to using a switch instead of an if/else.

Comment: @Dan: no, the only comparison *you* can think of is against zero.

Comment: Using pointers to global/static objects would make sense to me, but they're not constant expressions: their addresses are assigned by the linker, and possibly relocated by the loader. Stack/heap are obviously right out. What does that leave, comparisons against `(intptr_t)-1` and the like?

Comment: Fine... the only platform-independent comparison you can make against it is 0.  I don't tend to assume that people asking basic questions like this will be comparing pointers against lists of memory mapped hardware registers, or something like that.

Comment: Although is an interesting workaround, I wasn't actually looking for a workaround; just an explanation. If I used this cast in real code it would signal a WTF (to me, at least).

Comment: @ Dan, Well, I guess that's the problem with passing judgment on the question and not addressing the question as asked. The question isn't "is it a good or bad idea to do this?".

Comment: As meeselet points out, while this is a good example of a workaround, it doesn't answer the question that was posed.

Comment: Fair enough...i think Jeff's answer is the best anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You can (if you really must). Simply cast the pointer to an *appropriately sized* integer.  For this `intptr_t` should be used.  That is not to say I'd recommend it, but you may have your reasons.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void we_can_switch_him(void *ptr)
{
    switch ((intptr_t)ptr) {
        case (intptr_t)NULL:
            printf("NULL!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("%p!\n", ptr);
            break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    void *foo = "toast";
    we_can_switch_him(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`case` labels expect a constant-expression, usually an integer, and pointers tend not to compare well against these except in the case of NULL.  You could cast to intptr_t, but it's still nonsensical when you only have one thing you can compare against.

`switch` statements exist because the compiler can often turn them into a [jump table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table), which is a concept that works best if your case labels are consecutive integers.  But in the case of a pointer casted to integral type, you gain nothing over an `if` / `else` by using switch except a more cumbersome syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It can be related to how switch is implemented - it seems to expect at most an integer so it can use a certain CPU register which might not be possible with a pointer.

Comment: This answer does not really make sense: Internally (in terms of CPU registers), pointers can also just be implemented as integers, so there really is no such limitation coming from the CPU registers AFAICS.

Answer (score 0):

The hitting the nail on the head answer is because switch statement need compile time things to compare to.  If you could do it with run-time data, I can see boatloads of reasons to do this.  In particular, say I want to figure out which function my function pointer is pointing to.  The switch construction being far more elegant than a bunch of if then else if statements.

Answer (score -1):

Doh! why even use a switch statement? switch statements should only be used if you have 3 or more options to choose from if you have 2 options then use an if(){} else {} statement.

joshua this is not a legitimate use of a pointer in a switch.

If you really must use a switch statement then cast it to an _int64 or long long or some integral type guaranteed to be as big as or bigger than a pointer  (depends on compiler).

Also some compilers may limit the maximum size of a switch to an int or some other arbitrary size. in this case you can't use a switch statement at all.

DC

Answer (score -1):

```
enum boolean
{
 FALSE=0,
 TRUE=!FALSE
}boolean;
...
void *ptr=NULL;
...
switch((!ptr))
{
 case FALSE:
  ...
  break;
 case TRUE:
  ...;
  break;
}
...
```

It's possible to switch on pointer.

Comment: The ptr here is implicitly converted to a switchable type by applying the '!' operator --> That's not a switch on pointers

Answer (score -3):

You only need this change in your switch:  [ptr intValue]

```
void why_cant_we_switch_him(void *ptr)
{
    switch ([ptr intValue]) {
        case NULL:
            printf("NULL!\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("%p!\n", ptr);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What syntax is this? What does `intvalue` refer to here? Please explain why (you think) this works?

Comment: @MatthijsKooijman This is objective-C, which was mentioned in the question, so I guess it's not as off-topic as it appears at first glance.

Comment: Ah, I had missed that, thanks for claryfing. My question still stands though: How does it work? I guess the `[ptr intValue]` syntax converts the pointer to an int? Might be useful to make that explicit in the answer?