# C++: how to switch through arguments?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, command-line, command-line-arguments

So I have code like

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    string outputUrl ;
    string outputContainer ;
    string outputUserName ;

    for(int i = 0 i>=argc; i+2){
        switch(argv[i]){ //C2450
            case "-server" : {outputUrl += (argv[i+1]);} break; //C2051
            case "-container" : {outputContainer = (argv[i+1]);} break; //C2051
            case "-nickname" : {outputUserName += (argv[i+1]);} break; //C2051
    }
}
```

Why does it give me compiler error C2450 and on next line C2051?
How to fix such thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `switch` statement can't use strings.  You'll need to replace it with a string of `if`-`else if` statements instead.

Answer (score 2):

C and C++ `switch` statements only operate on integral types. You can do some stuff like casting the pointer to an `int` (and in fact you are switching on pointers), but you're still not going to get 'switching on strings' behavior like you want here.

[Why no switch on pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308323/why-no-switch-on-pointers)

Answer (score 2):

You can switch on numbers, not on pointers to strings. I take it you're transitioning from another language?

Also, i+2 should be i+=2.

Also, i>=argc should be i < argc

Comment: Yeah, that `for` statement is completely broken isn't it? I didn't notice.

Comment: I actually started writing "Where to begin..."

Answer (score 1):

You can't switch on strings, only integer types. You will have to explicitly if/else each one. Secondly, break occurs inside the case statement, not outside.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the breaks; it's just that there's a redundant set of brackets for each case.

Answer (score 1):

You [can't switch on a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdtytxhd%28VS.80%29.aspx), or anything else that isn't an integer or can't be converted to one. Use three "if" statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like getopt.  There is a nice (but not complete) implementation: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/xgetopt.aspx?msg=614581.  Or use boost.Program_options: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/index.html.