# Switch-case with pointers

Tags: c, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why no switch on pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308323/why-no-switch-on-pointers)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  void* not_a_pointer = 42;
  switch(not_a_pointer)
  {
    case 42:
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

.

```
error: switch quantity not an integer
```

How can I portably use a switch-case for the value of a variable with a pointer type? The reason for this is that one of the callback functions in an API I'm using has a void* argument.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308323/why-no-switch-on-pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try casting to `intptr_t`, which is an integer type:

```
switch((intptr_t)not_a_pointer)
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the `void*` isn't really a pointer, cast it back to an `int` before trying to use it in the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  void* not_a_pointer = 42;
  switch((int)not_a_pointer)
  {
    case 42:
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an integer to a callback API that passes a `void *`, the intention is that you pass the address of the integer.  Note that this might mean you need to do dynamic allocation:

```
int *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
*foo = 42;
register_callback(cbfunc, foo);
```

Then in the callback:

```
void cbfunc(void *arg)
{
    int *n = arg;

    switch (*n) {
        case 42:
    }

    free(arg);
}
```

(You *can* coerce an integer into a `void *` and back, but the conversions are implementation-defined.  The `void *` to `intptr_t` / `uintptr_t` to `void *` round-trip is required to be value preserving, but the inverse is not.  It's ugly, anyway.).

Comment: The conversion is implementation-defined, but you can instead use a `char *` that's a known offset from a base, e.g. convert `int i;` to `void *p` by `p=base+i;` and recover `i` by `i=(char*)p-base;` The `base` should be a `static const char` array of sufficient size to support the range of integers you need (for strict portability) with the `const` cast away. (Whether this is useful, I somewhat doubt; the dumb conversion should work on all real-world implementations.)

Comment: It's still ugly, though.  Another alternative is to define callbacks that use a `union { void *p; long l; }` as the type of their context argument.

Comment: Just curious; what would be the advantage of using malloc for one integer? Wouldn't it be more efficient to just declare and initialize foo as 42, then pass its address (&foo)?

Comment: @caf - `union { void *p; intptr_t i; uintptr_t u; };` might be better

Comment: @kaykun: The advantage of `malloc()` here is explicit lifetime management.  If you know that `foo` will live until the callback is finished, and that it won't be modified again until the callback is finished, then you can indeed just directly pass its address.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Well, I was talking about modifying both the callback and the caller of the callback, so you could really use whatever types you wanted.