# Is it possible to use function pointer in switch case?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, switch-statement, c-preprocessor

I'm using a function pointer based state machine.
I need a function to check for different stats. The amount of functions is pretty massive. Therefore I would like to not use if else if else... chains. I would like to use a swithc case statement:
I used the following code:

```
    switch (my_state_func)
    {
       case &idle_state_func:
       case NULL:
          //...
          break;
       case &failed_func:
          break;
       default:
          break;
    }
```

Now the compiler tells me I can't use pointer in switch case

Is there a way to fix this? I tried integer casting of the pointer.
This generates the error:

label doesn't reduce to an integer constant

```
case (int)&idle_func:
```

Is there maybe a macro or somthing? Logically it should be possible since every function point is a integer.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Isn't the point of function pointers that you can just call them without a `switch`? This looks a bit like a design problem.

Comment: case-labels need to be `int` literals. `(int)&idel_func` isn't one.

Comment: Another duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2308323/694576

Comment: Yes i could use a additional status flag. Then i need to change the flag in every state to indecate errors and other stuff. I personally think a nicer solution is the usage of a dummy function to identicat an error state. This would fit more into the logical construt of a state machine